# Why does setViewControllers not trigger viewWillDisappear and dealloc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

If I don't add `[detailNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` before `[detailNavigationController setViewControllers:...]` viewControllers those are pushed until `setViewControllers` does not receive viewWillDisappear and does not get deallocated. I checked and I am forwarding `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.. and I also tried to add `automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers` and separately `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` to return YES (even though the default is already YES). Those didn't work too.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code of the methods that you are trying to debug? Without the code, it will be hard to determine where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

call autorelease on viewcotroller before settingViewControllers

```
TestViewController * testView = [[[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName @"TestViewController" bundle: nil]autorelease];
[self.navigationcontroller setViewControllers: @[testView] animated: YES];
```

Comment: how do you know they are not using ARC?

Comment: if they are using ARC it would be autoreleased automatically